# iPhone EventKit Adding Event Custom Parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, eventkit

I am letting the user add events to the calendar in my app.

My question is, can I add a custom field to the view when the user goes to add an event, an example, a 'Birthday' field with a switch or tick box (that I can deal with) so they suer can record custom stats.

Is it possible to add this?

Thanks.

Comment: Any updates regarding this? Or is it even to pass custom fields so that we can display custom data in the calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up simply creating my own table view controller, display the event attributes and make the events manually rather than using the EKEventViewController.